# Entity framework core with SQL Server and JSON Patch?

Tags: json, .net-core, entity-framework-core, patch

Can anyone tell me what the limitations are of using JSON Patch with EF Core and SQL Server as the provider are?

We are trying to implement an API and our UX designers are demanding we update our object graphs with one save command so we figured json patch would be ideal so we started implementing it in Angular with fast-json-patch from NPM.

However we are seeing issues with things like removing an object from another objects collection navigation property.  Fast-json-patch generates a patch that would remove it from the "array", but doesn't actually delete the resource.

So is JSON Patch not intended for SQL Server backed EF Core? Is there some other implementation for json patch we should be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately we figured out that we had to implement a soft delete.

The json patch library we are using in Angular wants to create patch operations for pure JSON backends so it tries to make optimized operation towards that goal.

So once we put in a soft delete bit the issue was solved.